# Is caching useful at all for self hosted runners

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, sonarqube, github-actions

I'm using a self hosted runner for building maven projects. While integrating with sonarqube I came across `action/cache`

```
      - name: Cache SonarQube packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.sonar/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
      - name: Cache Maven packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
        run: mvn -B verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=XYZ
```

and although theoretically I understand the need to reuse dependencies when using Github runner(because they are all clean slate), I'm confused if there's any relevance when using a self hosted runner. The ~/.m2 folder does not get wiped out in my runner instance after workflow runs. So is there a need to save(cache) .m2 or .sonar folders?

Comment: At the moment `actions/cache` will only store caches on GitHub itself; this is true whether your runner is `self-hosted` or `GitHub-hosted`. Obviously the question about whether this makes sense for your self-hosted runners, network-wise, is an important one. If you're caching **computed data** then it's probably a win! If you're caching to avoid **network cost**, then it may be that your cache restore is almost as expensive as running `mvn install`.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/18549) on the Github Community has some interesting statements as well :)